# Unable to resolve modules @unimodules/core for expo46 and reactnative 0.69.6?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an error
"Unable to resolve module @unimodules/core from D:\react-native-tutorial\node_modules\expo-gl\build\GLView.js: @unimodules/core could not be found within the project or node_modules"

I searched other questions and it seems that this issue should have been resolved after expo version 43. I am on expo 46 so im not sure how to resolve this problem. my package.json looks like :

```
{
  "name": "react-native-tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.2",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^4.0.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native": "^0.8.0",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "expo": "~46.0.13",
    "expo-asset": "^8.6.1",
    "expo-camera": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~13.3.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "firebase": "^9.6.11",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve this issue? I have similar issue.